# Как запустить отдельную ячейку в jupyter notebook из командной строки

Tags: windows, bat, jupyter-notebook

У меня есть ссылка на файл jupyter notebook, который я открываю в браузере. Доступ к файлу есть только по ссылке. Мне нужно выполнить код отдельной ячейки в данном ноутбуке, прописав это в bat-файле. Как это сделать?